# Python Text File Line indentation

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i'm currently making this code to grab a string variable and insert it into a text file. This alone works. However, when putting stuff like '/n' on the end of the string to make it go to a new line. That does not work.

```
studentInformation = []
studentNumber = ("Enter amount of students: ")

for i in range(o, studentNumber):
        studentInformation.append(studentNumber)
        studentID = input("Enter student ID: ")
        studentEmail = input("Enter student email: ")
        studentPhrase = studentID + "#" + studentEmail
        studentInformation[i] = studentPhrase
        print (studentPhrase)

        objectFile = open("textFile.txt", "a")

        objectFile.write('/n'.join (studentPhrase))

        objectFile.close
```

My problem is that the output in the file wont be indented onto the next line. The output will all be put onto the same line.

Comment: Newline is `\n`, not `/n`...

Comment: `NameError: name 'o' is not defined`. PS  `\n`?

Comment: Also. `studentNumber = int(input(("Enter amount of students: ")))`

Comment: Read a short paragraph of official documentation and realize your simple typographical mistake https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines

Comment: @Hazy, you may consider accepting an answer that helped you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `\n` instead of `/n`
2. You need to have a number instead of just a string for the loop. i.e.

`studentNumber = int(input(("Enter amount of students: ")))`

3. You need to append the new line char at the end of the print statement.

Hence:

```
studentInformation = []
studentNumber = int(input(("Enter amount of students: ")))

for i in range(0, studentNumber):
        studentInformation.append(studentNumber)
        studentID = input("Enter student ID: ")
        studentEmail = input("Enter student email: ")
        studentPhrase = studentID + "#" + studentEmail
        studentInformation[i] = studentPhrase
        print (studentPhrase)
        objectFile = open("list.txt", "a")
        objectFile.write(studentPhrase + '\n')
        objectFile.close
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter amount of students: 3
Enter student ID: 123
Enter student email: em@gmail.com
123#em@gmail.com
Enter student ID: 2
Enter student email: abc@fgh.com
2#abc@fgh.com
Enter student ID: 1
Enter student email: olp@olp.com
1#olp@olp.com
```

**OUTPUT (from the file)**:

```
123#em@gmail.com
2#abc@fgh.com
1#olp@olp.com
```